# systemd service lacks permission to list files

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I set up a [MLFlow](https://mlflow.org/) a remote tracking server as a systemd service on Ubuntu ([here](https://datasmarter.imprint.to/post/mlflow-to-build-a-model-production-chain) the tutorial I followed). In a nutshell, I run programs in python and send some metrics and files to a remote server through sftp.

In `etc/systemd/system` I defined a `mlflow-tracking.service` file like so:

```
[Unit]

Description=MLflow server

After=network.target 


[Service]
    
Restart=on-failure
    
RestartSec=20
    
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=_mypath_/anaconda3/envs/mlflow_server/bin/:$PATH exec mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://mlflow:mlflow@localhost/mlflow --default-artifact-root file:_mypath_/MLFLOW_SERVER/mlruns -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000' 

        
[Install]
        
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything seems to work fine as long as file transfer from my machine to the remote server is concerned: all the files end up where they are supposed to. However, in the MLFlow UI I receive the following error message:

> Unable to list artifacts stored
> undersftp://192.XXX:*mypath*/MLFLOW_SERVER/mlruns/bc899e79336b461d9ca86d7dbcc37abf/artifacts
> for the current run. Please contact your tracking server administrator
> to notify them of this error, which can happen when the tracking
> server lacks permission to list artifacts under the current run's root
> artifact directory.

Where `192.XXX` is the ip of the remote machine where the service is running and `bc899e79336b461d9ca86d7dbcc37abf/artifacts` is one of the folders I write files to.

Is there a reason why a service might lack permissions to list the files in a local folder?
Note that the permissions of all the folders are `drwxrwxr-x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP connect with `user@192.XXX` - `user` is the remote-user having the permission for the directory and files.

SSH login to remote sftp machine.

run `whoami` or better run `id`

the username/group should match the owner+permission to `ls -l /mypath`

Comment: they do match. I also tried to modify the service specifying User = _myuser_ under [Service] (does it make sense to try that?). However, I get the same error

Comment: Specifying User = myuser ended up working after a `sudo systemctl restart mlflow-tracking.service`